# All possible signatures with numba vectorize

Tags: gpu, numba-pro

I am new to Numba and GPU programming with Python.

I understand basic signatures used with `vectorize` decorator.
For example :- For a method that accepts two `float` variables and return a `float` , this is the signature `@vectorize([float64(float64, float64)])`

I have 3 questions
1.What is the signature to accept and return `Numpy` arrays?
2.What is the signature to accept and return `Pandas` Dataframe?
3.What are the possible signatures available ?